# With a NavigationDrawer: fragments or activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am starting to develop my app and I implemented a NavigationDrawer and I've got a simple question. Should I use Fragments or Activities to display each "content". I mean, I read that Fragments are better, but in this case I would only have like one Activity for almost every part o my app...

What do you think? I should decide now which approach I'm going to use.

Comment: It depends on ur app .